# Thonny returns error when installing nextcord.py package

Tags: pi-4, packages

When trying to install `nextcord.py` from the thonny package manager, this exception is raised, no matter the version:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting nextcord
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nextcord (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for nextcord


Process failed, return code: 1
```

---

Is there a way to fix this? If not, is there an alternate way of installing the package?

---

**EDIT 1**: After installing python3.8 as [this website](https://itheo.tech/install-python-3-8-on-a-raspberry-pi/), It now returns the following exception:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting nextcord
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/nextcord/nextcord-2.0.0a3-py3-none-any.whl (1.0MB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0 (from nextcord)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/f5/90ede947a3ce2d6de1614799f5fea4e93c19b6520a59dc5d2f64123b032f/aiohttp-3.7.4.post0.tar.gz (1.1MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 305, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 214, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source.py", line 70, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    reqs = self.req.pep517_backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 70, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 162, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable


Process failed, return code: 2
```

Comment: See e.g. https://pypi.org/project/nextcord/. It requires Python 3.8+. Which version do you run? Raspbian Buster provides Python 3.7 by default

Comment: Unfortunatly, thonny (prroably) runes on python 3.7... I'll have to fix that...

Comment: @Dirk I've installed python 3.8, but I receive another exception. I've edited my post to include this info.

Comment: Searching for that error msg suggests it may help installing with `--no-use-pep517`. I suggest you do some more research before using that though

Comment: FYI: The successor of Raspbian buster (bullseye) has just been released and that has Python 3.9 installed. There are still teething problems with Bullseye though...